Change AVAssetDownloadTask's download destination
I am using AVAssetDownloadTask to download HLS content for caching purposes:
guard let task = assetDownloadURLSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(
    asset: asset.urlAsset,
    assetTitle: asset.urlAsset.url.lastPathComponent,
    assetArtworkData: nil,
    options: nil
) else { return }

task.resume()

However, this by default downloads the videos to a public directory users can see in Settings > General > iPhone Storage. I do not want this behaviour and instead want it saved in the app's /tmp directory.
Right now I am following Apple's documentation for setting up persisting HLS content, and in the delegate for handling the data finishing transfer, I copy the file data over to /tmp :
let tempDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
let newURL = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent(asset.name)
try fileManager.moveItem(at: downloadURL, to: newURL)

This works fine, however, if something happens and the file is only partially downloaded, it will still appear in Settings as it did not reach the stage of being moved to /tmp and I'd like to avoid that. Sure there are ways I can try to mitigate this issue but what seems like the obvious option is if I can somehow just change where the file is being downloaded in the first place to avoid having to manually move the file over to /tmp afterwards.
I found out that there actually exists a variation of makeAssetDownloadTask that lets you define a destinationURL where to download the file to, however this has been deprecated. Is there no way for me to define a destinationURL in the new method they provide?
